# Testing AngularJS controllers with resource services

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, karma-runner

**Background:**
I'm writing unit test for angular js controllers, which utilize angular $resources wrapped in services (for maintainability purposes).

**Example controller:**

```
name = 'app.controllers.UsersIndexCtrl'
angular.module(name, [])
.controller(name, [
  '$scope'
  '$location'
  '$dialog'
  'Users'
  'UserRoles'
  ($scope, $location, $dialog, Users, UserRoles) ->
    # Get users list
    $scope.users  = Users.query()

    # rest...

])
```

**Example resource service:**

```
angular.module('app.services.Users', [])
.factory 'Users', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$resource', '$location' , ($rootScope, $http, $resource, $location)->
  baseUrl = '/users'
  Users = $resource baseUrl + '/:userId', {userId: '@_id'}

  Users.getStatus = ->
    console.log 'User::getStatus()'
    req = $http.get baseUrl + '/status'
    req.success (res)-> 
      $rootScope.globalUserAccountSettings = res
      unless $rootScope.$$phase then $rootScope.$apply()

  # other, custom methods go here...
])
```

Most of unit test examples in angular suggest using $httpBackend and thus mocking the $http service in controllers. To be honest, I doubt if it's a good practice since if did so I'd have to hardcode request paths in all controller tests and I want to isolate unit behaviour. $httpBackend mock is really great but only if you are using $resource in controllers directly.

**A typical single test using $httpBackend would look like:**

```
it 'should be able to add a new empty user profile', ->
  $httpBackend.flush()
  l = $scope.users.length
  $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/users').respond _.cloneDeep mockResponseOK[0]
  $scope.add()
  $httpBackend.flush()
  expect($scope.users.length).toEqual l + 1
```

What if I created a mock User resource class instance, something like:

```
angular.module('app.services.Users', [])
.factory 'Users', ->
  class Users
    $save:(cb)->
    $remove:->
    @query:->
    @get:->
```

Angular [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) mechanisms will override old 'app.services.Users' module with this one in a transparent way and enable me to run checks with jasmine spies.

**What bothers me is the fact that I wasn't able to find a *single* example supporting my idea. So the question is, which one would you use and why or what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes much more sense to stub this at a service level with Jasmine spies, as you suggested. You're unit testing the controller at this point, not the service -- the exact way in which an http request is made should not be a concern for this test.

You can do something in your spec like this:

```
var Users = jasmine.createSpyObj('UsersStub', ['query', 'get']);
beforeEach(inject(function($provide) {
  $provide.factory('Users', function(){
    return Users;
  });
});
```

And then in your relevant tests, you can stub the individual service methods to return what you expect using methods like "andCallFake" on your spy object.

Comment: beforeEach(module(function($provide) { ... instead of inject?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is make a fake resource with the methods that were suppose to be called:

```
var queryResponse = ['mary', 'joseph'],
    Users = function() {
    this.query = function() {
      return queryResponse;
    },
    scope, HomeCtrl;
};

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {$scope: scope, Users: new Users()});
}));

it('has users in scope', function() {
    expect(scope.users).toEqual(queryResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie at this stuff. I've been writing my tests using coffeescript using a dsl, but I've ran into a similar problem today. The way I solved it was by creating a jasmine spy for my resource. Then I created a promise. When the promise is resolved, it will call the 'success' function that you pass in in the controller. Then in the 'it' method, I actually resolve the promise.

I think the code would look something like this using js and jasmine, but I didn't actually have time to check

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q ) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  queryPromise = $q.defer()
  User = jasmine.createSpyObject("UsersStub", ["query"]);
  User.query.andCallFake(function(success,errror){queryPromise.promise.then(success,error)});
  HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {$scope: scope, Users: new Users()});
}));

it('has users in scope', function() {
  queryPrmomise.resolve({User1: {name"joe"})
    expect(scope.users).toEqual(queryResponse);
});
```